# Convert String to Double (without using "Convert Class")

Tags: c#, string, double

Imagine I have the following values in a string, example:

```
string[] values  = new string[] { "17.424", "44.43", "44.0"};
```

Now I need to extract the exact value with the respective comma and save them as Double Numeric Type.

```
double valuesCorrectType;
```

I don't want to use this:

```
Convert.ToDouble(string);
```

because the output I get is: 17424.0 and 4443.0 and 44.0

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you saying the value you want to convert is really "17.424, 44.43, 44.0" i.e. it's not an array?

Comment: Those values are an example of Coordinates from a map. I can have multiple double values but they are in a string. 

I need to extract those values and save them on a double numeric type variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble("17.424", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Its your current culture which is considering `.` as thousand separator.

You can also use `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`, but you have to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: I read about that but didn't understand very well how to use it, because the specific points are Coordinates from a map. I can have 3 or 2 or 1 (or more) values after comma. "." isnt a separator of thousand values.

Comment: "The character used as the thousands separator.
In the United States, this character is a comma (,). In Germany, it is a
period (.). Thus one thousand and twenty-five is displayed as 1,025
in the United States and 1.025 in Germany." For your understanding see: [Globalization Step-by-Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/goglobal/bb688127.aspx)

Comment: Yes thank you. I was worried about values like this "13,23534534" but it seems it works perfectly for those numbers.